# Convert iPad NavController To Split Screen Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

So I made my iPhone app universal, it created a new mainWindow xib file for the iPad, and it has a UINavigation Controller which works fine.  I want to use a UISplit Screen Controller and put the rootview as the bigger view.  I tried doing this but it didn't work and I just ended up with rootview with no navbar and no split screen.

In appDidFinisLaunching, I have:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
//    if (NSClassFromString(@"UISplitViewController") != nil && UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) 
//    {
//        self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
//    }
//    else
//    {
//        self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
//    }
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

My "RootViewController" is a UIView Subclass with a UITableView Object.

And this is what my IB currently looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple' UISplitScreenController container object is always the root.
This contains a master viewController and a detail viewController.
The Detail is effectively the child and is the larger of the two.

You cannot do what you are trying to do - at least not with Apple's splitViewController.

From Ios5 you will be able to write your own containers though.

Alternatively, you could also look at MGSplitViewController:
https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController

Comment: What are you talking about I can't do what I want to do?  All I want to do is use a UISplitViewController...

Comment: According to Apple, their UISplitViewController should always be the first viewcontroller - and not inside a tabbar or a navigation bar. If you just want to use a UISplitViewController then there are plenty of tutorials to show you how if you search.